VBA code names the saved PDF with .xlsm.pdf
My code is designed to automatically create a PDF, save it to a specific location and open it. The PDF must be named after the name of the Excel file or the value in cell L3 (the values are the same). However, the code names the saved pdf "example.xlsm.pdf." I understand that the .pdf ending is necessary, .xlsm ending is not. How would I fix or change my code to name the file properly?
Sub PDF()

If Range("D51") = "name1" Then

On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
FileName:="C:\Users\example\Documents\" & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True

ElseIf Range("D51") = "name2" Then

On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
FileName:="C:\Users\tree\Documents\" & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True

ElseIf Range("D51") = "name3" Then

On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
FileName:="C:\Lone\" & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True

End If


End Sub


The code firsty looks at names in the D51 cell. It then saves the PDF in a specific location for every user, and opens the said PDF.

You have to remove the extension - as it is always returned with Activeworkbook.Name
Public Sub saveAsPdf()

Dim Filename As String
Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Filename = Left(Filename, InStrRev(Filename, ".") - 1) 

Dim Path As String
Select Case ActiveSheet.Range("D51")
    Case "name1"
        Path = "C:\Users\example\Documents\"
    Case "name2"
        Path = "C:\Users\tree\Documents\"
    Case "name3"
        Path = "C:\Lone\"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Unknown path in D51", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
End Select


If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) <> "" Then

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=Path & Filename, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
Else
    MsgBox "Folder " & Path & " doesn't exist"
End If

End Sub

Furthermore you should avoid On error resume next.
You can check for the path - either by using a check when reading it into the path-variable - or by using Dir.

Your solution works very well, thanks. it however leaves the name with two dots. "example..pdf" I also have another problem that I have not mentioned before. I have 2 computers that are used by everyone. Now the name in the D51 is always one of those 3, so if the path was not found it would just save the pdf in a specific path. If you or anyone else has an idea how to resolve that it would help a lot.

Updated the code to only return filename w/o dots. But I don't understand your new requirement ...

If I delete the dot in the filename, the pdf gets named with the .xlsm.pdf, as previously "example.xlsm.pdf".  As for the other requirement, I'm sorry for poor explanation, will try again. The first 3 names and save locations are specific for each users personal computer. But I also want to use this excel file in another computer, which has a different save location, but the same name must remain in the D51. So I need a way for the code to be able to save the pdf on another PC which doesn't have a user, with one of the 3 names in the D51.

Sorry - fixed the code too fast. This is correct Filename = Left(Filename, InStrRev(Filename, ".") - 1) 

Regarding your additional requirement: "So I need a way for the code to be able to save the pdf on another PC which doesn't have a user" - how should the code know where to save the file????

not a problem, thanks for the fix. The PC that does not have a user (actually 2 PCs) have the same path to the documents folder (C:\Users\mermes\Documents).
